# Story identification: late 80s book where protagonist earns living from what nowadays we'd call microtransactions on articles he's written online

Tags: story-identification, books

I know this seems way ahead of its time but I definitely read this in the late 80s/ early 90s.
He rarely left his apartment and something he wrote went viral & earned him loads.

Comment: Was this a full-length novel or a novella? Was it definitely a male? Do you remember anything about his background such as age or nationality?

Comment: It was a full length novel. Definitely not Heinlein & pretty sure no-one else I was familiar with.

Comment: Male protagonist, not sure if his age was mentioned but he wasn't particularly young. I seem to remember the stuff he wrote was a bit dry & scholarly.

Comment: I keep thinking there was a sort of alien invasion he or someone he know was involved in, but then I realise I'm thinking of Pohl's Age Of Pussyfoot, which it isn't.

Comment: Neal Stephenson's Snow Crash has a character post lots of little snippets of information he's seen or overheard to people who pay him a tiny amount each time e.g. a Movie exec is talking about how much he likes the idea of someone blowing up cars in a junkyard with a rocket launcher, he's overheard and lots of desperate screenwriters can bombard him with junkyard/rocket launcher scenes.